# Compare two objects in Java using reflection and annotations

Tags: java, reflection, casting, annotations

I have a sample Student object, which has several fields (index number, name, family name, etc.).  I'd like to compare two Student objects, but I'd like to define what is the priority of field comparison. For this purpose, I use field annotations, like in the example below:

Annotation interface definition:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface CompareOrder {
    int order();    
}
```

The usage:

```
@CompareOrder(order = 3)
private int indexNumber;
@CompareOrder(order = 2)
private String name;
@CompareOrder(order = 1)
private String familyName;
private ArrayList <Float> marks;
@CompareOrder(order = 5)
private float average;
@CompareOrder(order = 4)
private boolean fullTime;
```

Some fields contain no annotation, and are ignored in comparison. The first thing I did, is extracting all fields of the class using reflection and sorting them according to the comparison order, which corresponds to the first part of my compareTo overriden function body:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student other) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Class<? extends Student>  clazz = this.getClass();
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    List <Field> fieldList = new ArrayList<Field> ();
    //ommiting unannotated fields
    for (Field f : fields)
    {
        if(f.getAnnotation(CompareOrder.class) != null) fieldList.add(f);
    }
    //sorting fields by compare order
    Collections.sort(fieldList, new Comparator <Field> (){

        @Override
        public int compare(Field f0, Field f1) {
            CompareOrder compOrder0 = f0.getAnnotation(CompareOrder.class);             
            CompareOrder compOrder1 = f1.getAnnotation(CompareOrder.class);             
            return compOrder0.order() - compOrder1.order();

        }
    });

    for (Field f : fieldList)
    {
        // HERE GOES COMPARISON OF OBJECTS FIELD BY FIELD, ACCORDING TO THE ORDERING
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And now I'm kind of stuck. Because at this point, I need to decide whether a field of this and other student is greater or smaller. And I can't do that with raw Object type, only thing I can do is call equals method, which is not enough. I need to know if it's greater or smaller. I need to cast it somehow to... yeah, what exactly? How do I extract the field type, and then cast? Is this even doable?

PS. I know, that possibly an easier approach is to use method annotations and invoke getter methods, but I'm just curious whether it is doable the way I'm trying to do it.

Comment: If you use java 8 you can compose comparators in the order that you want, avoiding all the annotation and reflection junk

Comment: Yes, I know. But I specifically need to do it using annotation and reflection. That is the exercise ;)

Comment: You can analyze the classes/types of the fields. All the simple types you can compare. Classes for Integer and friends, Character or String implement Comparable. Other fields may or may not be Comparable, too; if not then game over.

Comment: Sorry, but that is actually the problem you are facing? If you use `field.getType()` you will get actual type of field so based on it you can use appropriate method to get value (like `field.getInt(instnace)`) and use correct comparator (like `Integer.compare(val1, val2)`). Also basic data types like `String` or wrapper classes like `Integer` implements `Comparable` interface so you can use `get()` instead of `getInt()` to get wrapper class instance and use `compareTo` method.

Comment: This may be fine for learning purposes, but don't ever use expensive operations like reflection in methods like `compareTo`. The better solution here is probably to use the field information to generate a `Comparator`, either in an annotation processor or runtime with bytecode generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) and something like

```
Class<Comparable> cls = Comparable.class;
for (Field f : fieldList) {
    if (cls.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())) {
        Comparable c = (Comparable) f.get(this);
        int r = c.compareTo((Comparable) f.get(other));
        if (r != 0) {
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ++ since this is only exercise, fields in OP examples will most probably be implementations of Comparable (since `get` is returning wrapper class instances), but lets remember that not all classes implement this interface (like collections).

Answer (score 0):

As you're already into reflection you can check if the fields that you annotate also implement the Comparable interface. Then you can compare them with the compareTo method that they implement.

If you have a field that's annotated and does not implement Comparable, then that should be an error (is it possible to restrict the annotation to fields implementing a special interface?).

Change the int fields to Integer and the other primitive types as well to their object counterparts and don't forget the null check when comparing.